# With the Storybook addon knobs, how to adjust dummy data?

Tags: reactjs, storybook

In my React Storybook, I'm using knobs and I would like to add a knob for dummy data. Here's my storybook component example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { boolean } from '@storybook/addon-knobs/react';
import { MySteps } from '../../src/components/index';

const steps = [
  {
    completed: true,
    title: 'xxxxxxx',
  },
  {
    completed: false,
    title: 'x',
  },
];

export default () => (
  <div>
    <MySteps
       steps={steps}
    />
  </div>
);
```

I want to add a knob like so:

```
export default () => (
  <GettingStartedSteps
    step_1_completed={boolean('Step 1 Completed', true)}
    step_2_completed={boolean('Step 2 Completed', false)}
    steps={steps}
  />
);
```

Is this dynamic dummy data possible with Storybook + knobs?

Comment: check this link it => https://dev.to/madhusudhansrinivas/storybook---ui-component-development-tool-for-react-vue-and-angular-article-focusing-on-react-29od